# как сделать закругленную снизу фигуру на css радиус был как здесь?

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Голубую фигуру надо закруглить,вот так не совсем точно выходит по середине не хватает выпуклости

```
border-bottom-left-radius: 100% 40px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 100% 40px;
```

Answer (score 3):

Чуть чуть геморойно но зато без SVG

за помощь в создании радиального градиента спасибо [@Artur](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/332241/arthur)

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.item {
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  min-height: 500px;
  background: #fcfcfc;
}

.item__top {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 150px;
  background-color: red;
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse, red 69%, #fff 70%);
  background-size: 260% 240px;
  background-position: -275% -330px;
  text-align: center;
}

.item__top h2 {
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  color: white;
}

.item__top p {
  width: 90%;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: auto;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="item__top">
    <h2>Заполните форму</h2>
    <p>и получите прайс-лист с актуальными расчетами оккумаемости
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

я бы делал это через svg фигуру - тогда и адаптивность будет

```css
.wrap {
 height: 500px;
 width:500px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.header {
 height: 100px;
 background-color: #3f59fa;
 position: relative;
}
.header__bottom {
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
 <div class="header">
  
  
 <svg class="header__bottom"  viewBox="0 0 491 17" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="3f59fa">
   <path d="M0.370992498,0 C327.013609,0 490.334917,0 490.334917,0 C490.334917,0 360.913687,17 239.052668,17 C157.811988,17 78.2514299,11.3333333 0.370992498,0 Z" id="Path" fill="#3F59FA"></path>
  </g>
 </svg>
  
  
 </div>
</div>
```

либо код svg использовать как отдельное изображение и поместить его в верстку через псевдоэлемент (::after), тогда html будет выглядеть чище

[пример на CodePen](https://codepen.io/MaxManchak/pen/wXXJRB)